# Finding the maximum for each subset of the same value

Tags: r

in the dataframe:

```
 > df
   Version.ID Relevant.product Proportion
        1000         OS        0.05095541
        1000         C         0.75159236
        1000         R         0.19745223
        1000         Other     0.00000000
        1000         C         0.75159236
        1000         C         0.75159236
        1000         C         0.75159236
        1000         C         0.75159236
        2000         O         1.00000000
        3000         En        0.93498526
        3000         En        0.93498526
        3000         En        0.93498526
        3000         R         0.06501474
        3000         En        0.93498526
        3000         En        0.93498526
        3000         Other     0.00000000
        3000         En        0.93498526
```

I would like to get the name of the product that has the maximum proportion for each of the Version.ID :

```
 Version.ID Relevant.product 
      1000           C
      2000           O 
      3000           En
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `data.table` library

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Relevant.product[which.max(Proportion)], by = Version.ID]

#    Version.ID V1
# 1:       1000  C
# 2:       2000  O
# 3:       3000 En
```

---

The above solution is very nice if you want only the first "Relevant.product" corresponding to `max(Proportion)`. If you're interested to return all of them instead, here's a way:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
idx = setDT(df)[, .I[Proportion == max(Proportion)], by=Version.ID]$V1
ans = unique(df[idx], by=c("Version.ID", "Relevant.product"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (which doesn't use any external package, but which is much less elegant):

```
x[row.names(x) %in% sapply(split(x, x$Version.ID),
   function(df)  row.names(df[which.max(df$Proportion),])),]
##    Version.ID Relevant.product Proportion
## 2        1000                C  0.7515924
## 9        2000                O  1.0000000
## 10       3000               En  0.9349853
```

Indeed, as David suggested, this solution is also slower. For 10000 rows and 10 classes we have:

```
x <- data.frame(Version.ID=as.factor(sample(1:10, replace=TRUE, 10000)),
                Relevant.product=sample(LETTERS[1:5], replace=TRUE, 10000),
                 Proportion=runif(10000))
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
 {data.table(x)[, Relevant.product[which.max(Proportion)], by = Version.ID]},
 {x[row.names(x) %in% sapply(split(x, x$Version.ID),
    function(df)  row.names(df[which.max(df$Proportion),])),]})

## Unit: milliseconds
## expr               min        lq    median        uq      max neval                                                                                
## [data.table]  3.802304  4.046833  4.124973  4.262634 80.18705   100
## [split]      11.171008 11.364131 11.502188 11.679067 14.51869   100
```

But it's good to know the alternatives :)

**EDIT**: Here are the results for 100000 rows:

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##                    min        lq    median        uq       max neval
## [data.table]  9.350692  13.88461  18.33646  68.44882  95.78928   100
## [split]      89.726972 106.39916 124.10599 169.41667 237.70003   100
```

and for 1000000 rows:

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##                    min        lq    median        uq       max neval
## [data.table]  76.58919  117.7388  155.9511  210.2772  362.0843   100
## [split]      963.87984 1190.5079 1395.7724 1602.5480 3417.5468   100
```

On the other hand, for 100000 rows and 1000 classes we get:

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##                      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
## [data.table]    39.55042  46.22971  48.59297  50.02435  133.3646   100
## [split]        844.62629 900.54373 916.15211 966.89630 1055.5050   100
```

Comment: It will be also much slower for a big data set- it will be good to bench mark though

Comment: Edit made, there you are

Answer (score 0):

Besides `data.table`, don't forget `dplyr`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  dt = dt[, .SD$Relevant.product[which.max(Proportion)], by = Version.ID],
  dplyr = unique(df %.% 
                   group_by(Version.ID) %.% 
                   filter(Proportion == max(Proportion)) %.% 
                   select(Version.ID, Relevant.product)
  ), 
  times = 1000
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
# dt    2.164455 2.274471 2.311025 2.390110 10.868671  1000
# dplyr 1.758137 1.846008 1.871316 1.916657  6.448726  1000
```

Init:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text="Version.ID Relevant.product Proportion
1000         OS        0.05095541
1000         C         0.75159236
1000         R         0.19745223
1000         Other     0.00000000
1000         C         0.75159236
1000         C         0.75159236
1000         C         0.75159236
1000         C         0.75159236
2000         O         1.00000000
3000         En        0.93498526
3000         En        0.93498526
3000         En        0.93498526
3000         R         0.06501474
3000         En        0.93498526
3000         En        0.93498526
3000         Other     0.00000000
3000         En        0.93498526", header=T)
dt <- data.table(df)
```

**Edit @DavidArenburg:**

Quite apart from the fact that the example data is tiny and the differences seem little, I dunno if this is a valid benchmark:

```
microbenchmark(
  dt = { data.table(df)[, .SD$Relevant.product[which.max(Proportion)], by = Version.ID] 
         df <- as.data.frame(df) 
       },
  dplyr = { unique(df %.% 
                    group_by(Version.ID) %.% 
                    filter(Proportion == max(Proportion)) %.% 
                    select(Version.ID, Relevant.product)
                   ) 
            df <- as.data.frame(df)
          }, 
  setdt = { setDT(df)[, Relevant.product[which.max(Proportion)], by = Version.ID] 
            df <- as.data.frame(df)
          },
  times = 1000
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq   median       uq        max neval
# dt    3.258985 3.445448 3.494130 3.580771   8.991382  1000
# dplyr 1.840736 1.937044 1.955497 1.992579  10.654265  1000
# setdt 2.879731 3.046159 3.091678 3.179549 100.604628  1000
```

Comment: Please try you benchmark again with `setDT(df)[, Relevant.product[which.max(Proportion)], by = Version.ID]`. I wonder if `setDT` improves the performance

Comment: @DavidArenburg See my edit - it's faster than `data.table()`.

Comment: `which.max(x)` is not equivalent to `x == max(x)` if there are duplicate maxima.